# How to solve segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement this simple bit of code for an assignment. It is part of a larger file, but I keep getting the segmentation fault error no matter which part of code I run. I'm not very experienced with coding, but if someone could help show me where I'm going wrong that would be great.

I've tried commenting sections to find the error but to no avail.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <cab202_graphics.h>
#include <cab202_timers.h>


void setup(double w, double h){
    clear_screen();
    // Draw Border
    draw_line(0,0,0,h-3,'|');
    draw_line(0,0,w-1,0,'-');
    draw_line(0,h-3,w-1,h-3,'-');
    draw_line(w-1,0,w-1,h-3,'|');
    // Draw Table
    draw_line(0,2,w-1,2,'-');
    draw_line(0,4,w-1,4,'-');
    draw_line((w/3)*2,0,(w/3)*2,4,'|');
    draw_line((w/3),0,(w/3),4,'|');
    // Draw Intersections
    draw_char(0,0,'+');
    draw_char(0,h-3,'+');
    draw_char(w-1,0,'+');
    draw_char(w-1,h-3,'+');
    draw_char(0,2,'+');
    draw_char(0,4,'+');
    draw_char(w-1,2,'+');
    draw_char(w-1,4,'+');
    draw_char((w/3)*2,0,'+');
    draw_char((w/3)*2,2,'+');
    draw_char((w/3)*2,4,'+');
    draw_char((w/3),0,'+');
    draw_char((w/3),2,'+');
    draw_char((w/3),4,'+');
    //Draw Charging Station
    draw_line((w/2)-4,5,(w/2)+4,5,'#');
    draw_line((w/2)-4,6,(w/2)+4,6,'#');
    draw_line((w/2)-4,7,(w/2)+4,7,'#');
    show_screen();
}

int main() {
    double w = screen_width();
    double h = screen_height();

    setup_screen();
    setup(w, h);
    return 0;
}
```

It should show a bordered screen with a table at the top and rectangular "charging station" below.

Comment: Hi perhaps run it under a debugger to see the stack frame?

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure how to do that as I'm very inexperienced. I'm using GCC to compile it as below:
"gcc Ass1-2.c -o Ass1-2 -Ic:/cab202/ZDK -Lc:/cab202/ZDK -std=gnu99 -lzdk -lncurses -lm -g -Wall -Werror"

Comment: Try adding the flag `-fsanitize=address` to your build and post the output of running your program.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The setup_screen() must be before the screen_width() and screen_height() functions. Since these are part of a non standard library I don't exactly know how they work, but this solves the problem.